# Pass message in Intent.putextra

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

I am displaying a username using Intent but I want to append welcome before its name I have tried this, so far but I am unable to get the result that I want.

```
myIntent.putExtra("User", username.getText().toString());
```

I am adding welcome so it comes before the username

```
myIntent.putExtra("Welcome"+"User", username.getText().toString());
```

it's not working please suggest what should be done!!!!

Comment: you are using it wrong way

Comment: instead of `myIntent.putExtra("Welcome"+"User", username.getText().toString());` use `myIntent.putExtra("User", "Welcome"+username.getText().toString()); `  in another activity use intent.getExtras().getString("User"); it will return the complete message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `putExtra("key", value)` method first parameter is key and the second is value and the key should be the same to get the value in the next activity

You Instead of

```
myIntent.putExtra("Welcome"+"User", username.getText().toString());
```

use

```
myIntent.putExtra("User", "Welcome "+username.getText().toString());
```

In the next activity use the below line, it will return the complete message

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String data = intent.getStringExtra("User");
```